# enquiry on uniformly distributed random numbers using python

Tags: python-3.x

please how can I randomly generate 5,000 integers uniformly distributed in [1, 100] and find the mean using python. I tried the function np.random.randint(100, size=5000), but I got below error message while trying to get the mean.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: `np.random.randint(1, 100, size=1000).mean()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [random.randint](https://numpy.org/doc/1.16/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html#numpy.random.randint):

```
import numpy as np

r=np.random.randint(0,100,5000)
```

Then use [mean](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) to find the mean of that:

```
>>> np.mean(r)
49.4686
```

You can also use the array method of `mean()`:

```
>>> r.mean()
49.4686
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
np.random.randint(1, 100, size=1000).mean()
```